# Interfacing BLE module to microcontroller

Tags: iphone, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect a BLE module to 8051 micro-controller. The 8051 microcontroller is 8 bit. While the assigned UUIDs are 16 bit and 128 bit. I have to make my own UUID for this? Or how can i convert a UUID to 8 bit ?

Comment: I'm confused, what does the microcontroller being 8-bit have to do with anything here? Your module just has to advertise a 16 or 128 bit UUID for its services. If it's one of the standard services, you use a a predefined 16-bit UUID for that, or you generate your own 128-bit UUID for a proprietary service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know,

You can only use 128-bit and the 16-bit are reserved for BLE standard. If you are just playing with it yourself, you can safely use a 16-bit UUID. If it is going to production and market, then better choose your 128-bit UUID.

What do you mean by converting the 128-bit UUID into 8-bit? You just pick a 128-bit UUID and stick with it. Of course, in your 8051, you can store 128-bit using 16 bytes of code memory.